# Why DataGridView ComboBox displays the ValueMember value?

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, datagridview, datagridcomboboxcolumn

I am currently working in C# window application. There I use data grid view combo box in the DataGridView. While clicking the drop down box it displays the Name field, if I select the name field from the drop box, it displays the value member value in DataGridView ComboBox.

Why I am not getting the display member value in the Combo box?

In databindindcomplete function I define the value for the ComboBox:

```
((DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)dgvItem_1.Columns["Student"]).DataSource = objDBContext.Stu_student;
((DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)dgvItem_1.Columns["Student"]).DisplayMember = "STUDENT_NAME";
((DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)dgvItem_1.Columns["Student"]).ValueMember = "STUDENT_ID";
```

If I select a value in the ComboBox following value displayed in drop down list

> Name
>   -----
>   Raja
>   Ramesh
>   Rani

If I select Raja in the list the ComboBox displays the corresponding STUDENT_ID in the ComboBox.  But I want to display the Student name in the ComboBox.

Can anyone tell me why I am getting the ValueMember value in the DataGridView ComboBox?

Comment: Which is the type of `objDBContext.Stu_student` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in my simple example where I've got a Student class that looks like:

```
public class Student
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public int StudentId{ get; private set; }
    public Student(string name, int studentId)
    {
        Name = name;
        StudentId= studentId;
    }

    private static readonly List<Student> students = new List<Student>
    {
        { new Student("Chuck", 1) },
        { new Student("Bob", 2) }
    };

    public static List<Student> GetStudents()
    {
        return students ;
    }
}
```

and I set up my binding for the combobox like this:

```
        DataGridViewComboBoxColumn comboBoxColumn = (DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)dataGridView1.Columns[0];
        comboBoxColumn .DataSource = Student.GetStudents();
        comboBoxColumn .DisplayMember = "Name";  
        comboBoxColumn .ValueMember = "StudentId";
```

I get my student names in the dropdown and when I select one, the selected name shows up in the cell.

Comment: thank you for your answer now i got display member in the ComboBox Text.